Is there a way to render a Razor view before the end of a controller method
I would like to render a "loading" view when a controller action starts processing code then at the end I want to return a view depending on the outcome of that action
//part of a controller

public async Task<IActionResult> Process()
{
    //here is where I would like to render the loading view
    View("Processing", "Processing");
            
    await ProcessData();

    //afterwards I want to either to redirect or ammend the loading view with a new model
    //this part works but the loading view never shows 
    if (successful)
       return View("Processing", "Processed successfully");
    return Redirect("RedirectUrl");
}


I also tried adding the loading view in its own action and use RedirectToAction but that didn't work either.

A controller action method can have only one return value (the View to be rendered), just like any other method. Your best option to do this is with JavaScript: any time a request is sent to the server, show a Loading spinner. When a response is received (the rendered View) it will replace whatever was showing, including the Loading spinner.

Use AJAX or a client-side approach that allows your front end to load the view immediately, then asynchronously handle the backend processing. Another way is to choose use meta tag which is a server-side approach to redirect to action after a specified delay.

For your shared code and scenario, I think you can try to use meta tag. The meta refresh tag will automatically redirect the user to action after a specified delay.
A simple demo you could follow:
Processing.cshtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Auto-refresh to the same action with the "startProcessing" flag set to true -->
    @if (ViewBag.Status == "Processing")
    {
        <!--1 seconds here, but you could set it to a few seconds if needed-->
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=@Url.Action("Process","YourController", new { startProcessing = true })" />

    }
</head>
<body>
    @if (ViewBag.Status == "Processing")
    {
        <p>Processing</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <p>@ViewBag.Status</p>
    }
</body>
</html>

Controller
public async Task<IActionResult> Process(bool startProcessing = false)
{
    if (!startProcessing)
    {
        // First request: Show Processing.cshtml
        ViewBag.Status = "Processing";
        return View("Processing"); 
    }
    //do your stuff for load the data and judge success or not by yourself
    // Second request: Perform the processing        
    if (successful)
    {
        ViewBag.Status ="Processed successfully";
        return View("Processing");

    }

    return Redirect("RedirectUrl");
}

